How to find the vector of a camera viewpoint in a 2d space to calculate the angle between the viewpoint and an object?
I'm using Python 3 to create a sound-game where you walk around in a 2D space and hear the objects in the space as you walk around.
I've already figured out how to spatialize the sound using the Ambisonics-toolkit for Supercollider where 0 is front, -pi is behind counter-clockwise and pi is behind clockwise in relation to the viewpoint of the player.
I already figured out how to calculate the angle between two vectors, but I'm struggling to understand how to find the two vectors I need from knowing the position of the player and the object and the viewpoint-angle of the player.
Can anybody help me out?
UPDATE 1
I'm using these functions:
# by: Alex Martelli
def dotproduct(v1, v2):
  return sum((a*b) for a, b in zip(v1, v2))
def length(v):
  return math.sqrt(dotproduct(v, v))
def angle(v1, v2):
  return math.acos(dotproduct(v1, v2) / (length(v1) * length(v2)))

# by me
def subtractVectors(v1,v2):
    x1 = v1[0]
    y1 = v1[1]

    x2 = v2[0]
    y2 = v2[1]

    x3 = x1 - x2
    y3 = y1 - y2
    return [x3, y3]

And if its to any help, this is what the documentation of the Ambisonics-transformer in Supercollider looks like:
FoaPush.ar(in, angle: 0, theta: 0, phi: 0, mul: 1, add: 0)

Arguments:
   in   
   The B-format signal, an array: [w, x, y, z]

angle   
   The distortion angle, in radians. -pi/2 to pi/2

theta   
   Azimuth, in radians.

phi 
   Elevation, in radians.

mul 
   Output will be multiplied by this value.

add 
   This value will be added to the output.

I guess the only parameter here I'll be modulating is the theta

Why is pi/4 front and not 0? Also, are you measuring angles starting clockwise from the player? (Most conventions measure it counter-clockwise)

You're right, my mistake. 0 is front, -pi is counter-clockwise to the back and pi is clockwise to the back.

If you have player position (x0, y0) and object position (x1, y1) and player facing angle theta (with angle being measure clockwise) then

The player to object vector is <x1 - x0, y1 - y0>
The player facing vector is <cos(theta), -sin(theta)>


Ok, so I tested it in the following way:
pangle = 0
ppos = [0,0]
opos = [-1,-1]
ovector = subtractVectors(ppos,opos)
pvector = [math.cos(pangle), -abs(math.sin(pangle))]
a = angle(pvector, ovector)
print(a)
and it prints 0.7853981633974484 (90 degrees right?) which the mirror of what I expected with object position being [-1,-1].
I guess maybe I didn't quite understand measuring clockwise / counter-clockwise? How could I get this angle to be -135, which is what I need for the Ambisonics-setup.

How does subtractVectors work? Does it give ppos - opos or opos - ppos? We want the latter, so that ovector = [-1, -1] and not ovector = [1, 1]. The angle it gave in radians also points to 45 degrees, not 90, which would be correct when comparing angle between [1, 1] and [1, 0] (but only when measuring positive angles counterclockwise!). You also do not need the abs on the sin.

Most builtin math stuff goes by convention where positive angles are measured starting from the 3 o'clock position and going anti-clockwise (e.g. 3 o'clock is 0 degrees, 12 o'clock is 90 degrees, 6 o'clock is -90 degrees or 270 degrees, etc...). If your toolkit uses an opposite convention and you're using that same kit to measure angles, then stick to their convention. If you are using something like numpy.angle then you want to be using standard convention.

Ah, subtractVectors is my own function, it does pos1 - pos2.
I'm not quite sure what my toolkit is using, I found it from a different thread in an answer by Alex Martelli (updating the OP with his and my functions):
This goes a bit over my head to be honest. Any suggestions on either how to use these functions, or how I might use numpy functions to get what I'm after?

Use subtractVectors(opos, ppos), otherwise your code is fine. The final angle is then according to standard convention. I would recommend you learn some basic vector math, otherwise you're really just coding blind here.
